# Is there a function to randomly lookup certain values with the same ID?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

E.g

```
Name | Product

John | A

Mary | B

Cary | C

John | D

Mary | E
```

Is there a way to do a random `Vlookup()`? For example if I were to lookup for John, either A or D will be shown.

Comment: What is your exact output desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Excel 2010` and later:

`=INDEX(B2:B6,INDEX(MODE.MULT(IF(A2:A6=E1,ROW(A2:A6)-MIN(ROW(A2:A6))+{1,1})),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(A2:A6,E1))))`

which will require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` for earlier versions of Excel.

Note that, if you are not using an English-language version of Excel, the separator within the array constant

`{1,1}`

may require amending.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XLOOKUP()` to search values either first to last or last to first.

```
=XLOOKUP(E1,A2:A6,B2:B6,,0,1)
```

Last parameter define search direction. To search last to first use `-1`.

To return all matching data you can use `FILTER()` function like-

```
=FILTER(A2:B6,A2:A6=E1)
```

> ***Edit:*** If you really need to show random result then use below formula.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B2:B6,A2:A6=E1),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(A2:A6,E1)))
```

[image]

Comment: To add to this. Once you have a filtered list, you can use RandBetween and Index to get get a random item from the filtered list

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. I will add that formula to my edits.

Comment: Is there a way to not involve the filter function? It seems that filter does not work on my excel worksheet. Don’t think my excel has XLOOKUP function haha.

Comment: @tiredaccountant what is your excel version?

Comment: Office professional Plus 2016